# Submit and going back on same button click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, href

I have a scenario where there is a form and it has a cancel button and a save button. If you hit cancel it should go back to the previous page as shown:

```
<a href="#/study">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
        data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="clear()">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></span> Cancel
</button>
</a>
```

I am using the simple anchor tag to achieve this. Now when the form is filled out and you hit the save button, it should call the create() method defined on the controller to create the object I want from the form input and go back to previous page

```
<a href="#/study">
<button type="submit" ng-click="go('#/study')" ng-       
        disabled="form.$invalid" class="btn btn-primary">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span> Save
</button>
</a>
```

Of course it does call the create method on the controller and saves the form input but would not go back to the previous page. I would highly appreciate any pointers in the right direction.

Comment: If you're doing your form submission in the controller, just put the go('#/study') call in the controller method for submission.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$location` service and its `path` method to redirect to specific path or use `$window.history.back()` to move to the last page.

```
app.controller('ctrl',function($scope, $location, $window){

    $scope.submit = function(){
        $http.post(...).success(function(){
            $location.path('/study');           
            //or            
            $window.history.back();
        });
    };

});
```

Button:

```
<button type="submit" ng-click="submit()" ng-       
        disabled="form.$invalid" class="btn btn-primary">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span> Save
</button>
```